# How do I understand a big c++ gaming project in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

Currently I am doing SFML- c++ as a basement in game development before starting out Unreal

When I see a game project in  SFML,  the codebase is huge, like above 30 classes, 100 functions, how can I get an idea of the code project, any suggestions about the usual standard class names in SFML projects and their purpose would be helpful.

Comment: 30 classes and 100 functions is huge? Oh boy, wait until you see really big projects...

Comment: oh.. then it is not huge ?  my bad.

Comment: A "huge" project has 100+ *files*

Comment: It's quite subjective calling something "huge". It most likely seems huge to you, because of the lack of structure or/and organization.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is nice, then the functions have a descriptive name, and you can basically skim through the main game loop to understand what it does.

If it's not that nice, then going throug the code with an inspector is probably your best option.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to understand for you is to go straight from main function, examining line by line. You don't need (and it doesn't make any sense) to go through all the methods of each class unless you really know where and why they're being used. So just go straight from the beginning, and you're good to go.